# Implement using gRPC library wire on Android. Decompressor is not installed for grpc-encoding "gzip"

Tags: android, grpc

I want to implement it using gRPC library wire on Android.
Communication with io grpc was successful using the structure defined in the proto file.
I'm asking because I'm trying to use the Wire Library but it doesn't work.

```
  fun runTest() {
        runBlocking {
            coroutineScope {

                launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    val uri = Uri.parse(BASEURL)
                    val grpcServiceClient = GrpcLoginServiceClient(GrpcClientProvider.grpcClient)
                    val loginObj = grpcServiceClient.Login()
                    val loginReq = LoginReq(AuthToken = "Hello",
                            Data = "Test")
                    loginObj.enqueue(loginReq, object: GrpcCall.Callback<LoginReq, LoginRes> {
                        override fun onFailure(
                            call: GrpcCall<LoginReq, LoginRes>,
                            exception: IOException
                        ) {
                            Log.v("LOG","wire req fail exception :$exception")
                        }

                        override fun onSuccess(
                            call: GrpcCall<LoginReq, LoginRes>,
                            response: LoginRes
                        ) {
                            Log.v("LOG","wire req success res:$response")
                        }

                    }
                    )

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The following exceptions occur
java.io.IOException: gRPC transport failure (HTTP status=200, grpc-status=12, grpc-message=grpc: Decompressor is not installed for grpc-encoding "gzip")

Also I'm not finding a sample of grpc source code using Android Wire library.
There's an Android sample on the Wire official github page, but there's only one message and the rcp block doesn't exist, so it's not helping at all.

Can I get help with the example source?